Conducting a network meta-analysis in R - inputting dichotomous data
I am looking to conduct a meta-analysis in R using {netmeta}. However, my outcome of interest is a little bit complex and would appreciate advice in how best to enter it into the dataset.
I am looking at the cleavage rate of oocytes for in vitro fertilisation following nutritional supplementation in cattle. Most of the studies do not state a mean +/- s.e.m. or s.d. in their results - they mainly report it as a proportion.
As cleavage is technically a binary outcome (has it cleaved? Yes or no?) I was going to convert the proportions to a risk ratio (which is fairly straightforward). However, one of the issues is that most of the studies collect oocytes on more than one occasion from the animals in the experiment. For example, they may have five animals in the control group and five animals in the experimental group, which undergo three oocyte collection cycles. However, the results of the three collections are just averaged for most studies, e.g. an average of 6/11 oocytes cleaved (54.5%) over the three collections and five animals in the control group and 9/15 (60%) in the experimental group. I feel like I need to account for the sample size of each study but just inputting 6 and 11, and 9 and 15 in the below columns: 
doesn't account for this.
Is it appropriate to just multiply the number of animals by the number of collections to estimate the total events and total numbers, or is that seriously oversimplifying it and potentially introducing sampling error?

There is a potential problem here, but I don't know if there's much that you can do about it in a meta-analysis.
The problem is that observations within an individual cow are likely to be correlated. Having 15 observations based on 3 collections from each of 5 cows is not the same as having observations on 15 individual cows. Within-cow correlations violate the assumption of independent observations that underlies many standard statistical analyses. There are ways to deal with that type of within-cow correlation, but it seems like they might not have been used in the reports that you are reviewing.
If there isn't data per cow in those reports, something close to what you propose is probably the best you can do. You should acknowledge that problem in your report as a limitation to the meta-analysis.
